# Sed - Replace all occurrences of a string in the second last line of a file

Tags: sql-server, regex, bash, sed

I have a bash script that I am using to modify a sql file (test.sql).

The sql file is as follows:

```
select count(*) from (
select 
I.ID,
I.START_DATE, 
I.END_DATE
from MY_TABLE I with (nolock)
where I.START_DATE >= '20170101' and I.START_DATE < '20170201'
) as cnt
```

I want to replace **all** the occurrences of the string `START_DATE` **but only** in the `WHERE` clause of the sql file.

So far, I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 'x; ${/START_DATE/s/START/END;p;x}; 1d' test.sql > new-test.sql
```

However, this returns the following new-test.sql file:

```
select count(*) from (
select 
I.ID,
I.START_DATE, 
I.END_DATE
from MY_TABLE I with (nolock)
where I.END_DATE >= '20170101' and I.START_DATE < '20170201'
) as cnt
```

The second occurrence of the string `START_DATE` in the `WHERE` clause is not being replaced.

How should I modify my sed expression so that I can achieve this?

Comment: you need to use `g` flag to replace all occurrences.. `s/START/END/g`... and you can use tac as well... `tac test.sql | sed '2s/START/END/g' | tac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
sed -e '/where/ s/START_DATE/END_DATE/g' -i test.sql
```

Explanation:

- operate only on lines that contain `where` (we "address" only the lines that match the regex pattern `where`)
- replace each occurrence of `START_DATE` with `END_DATE` - notice the "global" flag `g` at the end
- the `-i` flag tells sed to edit the file "in place" (no need to redirect output).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GNU sed` then you can use the following command

```
sed '/WHERE/I s/START_DATE/END_DATE/g' test.sql > new-test.sql
            ^                        
            |-------------------------- case insensitive match; GNU sed only
```

The capital `I` tells `sed` to perform a case insensitive match. This comes in handy when dealing with case insensitive SQL commands.

If you do not have GNU sed then case insensitive matching is a bit more complicated:

```
sed '/[wW][hH][eE][rR][eE]/ s/START_DATE/END_DATE/g' test.sql > new-test.sql
```

Simply adding the global `g` option at the end of the `s` command will make your solution work, too.

```
sed 'x; ${/START_DATE/s/START/END/g;p;x}; 1d'
```

However, it will break if the file has a trailing newline. I strongly recommend to search (case insensitively) for the `WHERE` clause and run the according substitution command.